# ¿Como podria hacer esto en ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

lo que quiero el nav se mantenga para todas las paginas de mi web, sin necesidades de llamarlo en todos los componentes esta es mi homepage

[image: Home]

Al darle click algun boton me redireccione pero que se mantenga nav

Comment: Por favor, añade tu código para evitar que tu pregunta termine cerrada

Comment: Agrega lo que hiciste.

Answer (score 1):

Si estas usando `react-router` solo tienes que renderizar el nav antes de definir tus rutas, algo así:

```
<Nav />
<Switch>
  <Route path="/path1" component={Component1} />
  <Route path="/path2" component={Component2} />
</Switch>
```

De este modo cuando accedas a `/path1` se mostrará primero el Nav y depues el `Component1`

Comment: comprendo, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

La solucion fue como me explico @tasio, con exact hago que sea la ruta absoluta donde se puede cargar el componente de botones y en componentes de las otras ruta uso arrow function para que me cargue el contenido que necesito en el otro path.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <PartidoState>
      <Router>
        <Navigator/>
        <Titulo/>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Canales}/>
          <Route  path="/espn" component={() => <EspnEmbbed/>}/>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </PartidoState>
  );
}
```